# css grid custom layout flow

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, css-grid

I need to make list of content, to be formatted, 
I have something

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
</div>
```

like this.  Number of items is dynamic and I always want first 6 would be in row mode all others in column. for example

```
- - - - - -
    - -    
    - -    
    - -    
    - -
```

in the item order should be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
    7 8
    9 10
    11 12
```

fill free to options, using grid or flex wrap

Answer (score 1):

Using grid would be like this

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  /* Create six columns and four rows */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 50px);
}

/* Select every second, starting at sixth */
.item:nth-child(2n+7) {
  /* Specify the column to put the item */
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, But as I mentioned its dynamic container so I don't know which items should have itemCol class

Comment: no, 6 was an example, in general content would be auto-fill first line but other lines would be center in content